# How do we capture component rendering in phases without Profiler API in React JS

Tags: reactjs, profiler, datadog

I want to capture component rendering time phase wise like how much time does a component takes to render UI in browser.
I tried with Profiler API https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/profiler.html - It is giving me required result,
but it is not recommended for production.
Is there a way to achieve this without Profiler API?
Also I need to create a graph in dataDog where I can display this time

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using Datadog, you should consider [Real User Monitoring](https://www.datadoghq.com/product/real-user-monitoring/). There is a [React integration](https://app.datadoghq.com/integrations/rum-react) that makes it very easy to start receiving traces, [browser events](https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/browser/), and logs from your React apps

Comment: Thank you @bwest I am using RUM Real User Monitoring.
And Currently I am specifically looking on how to capture component rendering time phase wise like how much time does a component takes to render UI in browser

Comment: The React integration I mentioned provides that. Have you configured it?